# How to read data from firebase realtime db in web?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I tried this code:

```js
    return firebase.database().ref('/pastrls/-M1akNXVk6VhnykRc-zN').once('code').then(function(snapshot) {
        var code = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().username) || 'Anonymous';
        document.write(code);
    });
```

[my db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bB9wI.png)

Comment: I'd suggest you add how the code you tried fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
return firebase.database().ref('/pastrls/-M1akNXVk6VhnykRc-zN').once('code').then(function(snapshot) {
        var code = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().username) || 'Anonymous';
        document.write(code);
    });
```

into this:

```
return firebase.database().ref('/pastrls/-M1akNXVk6VhnykRc-zN').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        var code = snapshot.val().code;
        document.write(code);
    });
```

First add a reference to the node `-M1akNXVk6VhnykRc-zN` and then use `once()` which will retrieve the data from the database. Then inside the callback function use `snapshot.val().code` to retrieve the `code` attribute.